# WiX Bundle not including MSI package

Tags: wix

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
       xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
         xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="t1bundle" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="Chanjet Ltd" UpgradeCode="87714fb5-9cdb-4323-af55-821c05974378" Compressed="yes" >
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"   >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="License.rtf"   LogoFile="banner.bmp"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <!--<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost"> IconSourceFile="$(var.Photoes)diaapp.ico"
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="$(var.Photoes)license.rtf"  LogoFile="$(var.Photoes)scon.ico"  />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>-->
    <Chain>
      <!--<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web"  />-->
      <!--<PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"  />-->
      <MsiPackage Id="t1plus" SourceFile="$(var.Version)/Sample.msi" Compressed="no"  DisplayInternalUI="yes"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
   <PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_40_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"/>
    <!--<PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCommand="/q"
          SourceFile="$(var.Dia)dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
          DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.0.30319&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.0.30319&quot;))"
                DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
            InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v5.1 OR VersionNT64 >= v5.1) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.0.30319&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.0.30319&quot;))"/>
    </PackageGroup>-->
     <util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40"/>
    <PackageGroup
            Id="Netfx4Full">
            <ExePackage
                Id="Netfx4FullExe"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="no"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="$(var.Version)/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                InstallCommand="/q /norestart "
                DetectCondition="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_40_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
                DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"/>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

As you see I want to do a .NET Framework check before installing my MSI.

I use:

```
light.exe -loc WixUI_zh-cn.wxl -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixBalExtension  1.0.0/bundle.wixobj
```

but the bundle.exe is only 567KB.
The MSI and dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe are not in the package.

Comment: you know i could not make dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe and my msi file in one package

Answer (score 0):

Change your ExePackage attribute Compressed to "yes"

Example:

```xml
<ExePackage Id="Netfx4FullExe"
            Cache="no"
            Compressed="yes"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            SourceFile="$(var.Version)/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
            InstallCommand="/q /norestart "
            DetectCondition="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_40_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
            DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"/>
```

See [the Wix documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html).